# How to append textbox with texts on the photo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, project

I am trying to create a project that making a photo slide like the link below.
And I want to add one more feature that I want to add unique individual text message within a textbox and append it to each photo.

I googled every website and hardly found a clue. Can anyone give me an advise or show me an example?

http://javascriptbook.com/code/c11/slider.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess the outermost `div` there is with class `"slider"`

So use this jquery

```
$(".slider").append("<input type='text' value='What-you-wish-to-write' />");
```

Comment: Also on change of each image you can do a `.find("input")` and use `val()` to change its value again